# Remove „Offers in app purchases” from iOS app

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, in-app-purchase

I would like to remove IAP from app on appstore and get rid of this info under get button:
[image]

I have to do some changes in AppStore connect? Maybe just change Xcode project config? I know that I can disable IAPs in AppStore connect, will deleting all do the trick?